# JSON (simple) parsing : null values

Tags: java, json

It's my first time working with a JSON file, so I went with simple JSON library. Here's what works:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
    import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
    
    public class TestClass {
        
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    
              JSONParser jsonP = new JSONParser();
              try {
                 JSONObject jsonO = (JSONObject)jsonP.parse(new FileReader("/Users/ryan/eclipse-workspace/JavaRentalCar/src/CarsBDD.json"));
             
                 String matricule = (String) jsonO.get("matricule");
                 String marque = (String) jsonO.get("marque");
                 String modele = (String) jsonO.get("modele");
                 System.out.println("Matricule: "+ matricule);
                 System.out.println("Marque: "+ marque);
                 System.out.println("Modele: "+ modele);
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
        }
```

My json file :

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "matricule": "01233A3E",
            "marque": "Tesla",
            "modele": "Model X",
            "kilometrage": 155,
            "boiteVitessse": "Automatique",
            "climatisation": true,
            "carburant": "Electrique",
            "categorie": "Classe A",
            "vehiculeEtat": "Bon",
            "disponibilite": true,
            "coutJour": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

When i run the code, Matricule, Marque and Modele are = to null.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You're attempting to access the `marque` property at the root node, which does not exist. This key only exists in the elements of the `cars` property. Acquire the `cars` property first, then get its 0'th element, then try to retrieve the properties you want.

Comment: As @Zulfe said, access ```cars ``` property first. ```cars``` is a json array. so create a json array for ```cars``` and then access the first json object ```0``` and then get ```marque``` as json key/value

Comment: And why not parse the whole file to json object then try to access the key as above comment suggested. Could lead to less lines to deal with